# How to make a html assets into scorm package?

Tags: jquery, html, scorm

```
**css
edge_includes
font
images
media
menu1_images
menu2_images
menu3_images
menu4_images**
index.html
index_edge.js
index_edgeActions.js
menu1.html
menu1_edge.js
menu1_edgeActions.js
menu2.html
menu2_edge.js
menu2_edgeActions.js
menu3.html
menu3_edge.js
menu3_edgeActions.js
menu4.html
menu4_edge.js
menu4_edgeActions.js


'Bold-folders'
```

This is the folder structure of my html asset here the menu1.html, menu2.html, menu3.html, menu4.html have link on index.html page, here when we click the link on index page. I dynamically load the appropriate page using jquery load function.

**My question is:**

How to convert this html asset into scorm package?"

Once it is done, how to see this scorm package in valamis player (www.valamiselearning.com)?

Comment: Can you explain why you want it to be a SCORM package? Even if the best approach to solve your problem is SCORM (which it might or might not be), the reasons for needing SCORM are important to understand how deep into SCORM you need to go.

Comment: Sharable Content Object Reference Model (SCORM) is a collection of standards and specifications for web-based electronic educational technology (also called e-learning). It defines communications between client side content and a host system (called "the run-time environment"), which is commonly supported by a learning management system. SCORM also defines how content may be packaged into a transferable ZIP file called "Package Interchange Format.

Comment: This question is too broad. If you're not familiar with using SCORM, and integrating SCORM into an HTML-based course, you should do a web search for tutorials. This is too complicated to be answered in a single StackOverflow post.

Comment: may you say 'where is the step by step instructional tutorial for scorm package of html assets?'' i found some of tutorial but i can't understand right procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify, i wasn't asking what SCORM is, I'm asking why you want to use SCORM - what's your motivation? What's your end goal?

Comment: hi Andrew, I wanna to host my html asset into LMS(Learning Management System) ,here LMS only accept and run the SCORM Package so if wanna to host any learning course like PPT,Flash,Word doc,etc in LMS, Everything must be converted as SCORM package.if you have any more ,let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt to directly answer your question -

You have a few options -

1. you build a page based SCORM page using a imsmanifest.xml following the rest of the packaging spec for either SCORM 1.2 or SCORM 2004.  This essentially means you'll set up an organization where each resource is a single page and the LMS can display those in a tree and the student will launch each one.  I put up a example of something like that here -https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki/Single-Pages-Managed-by-LMS-Navigation
2. you go the route you're asking about using AJAX to load in subsequent pages.  These types of players commonly need more thought as if you set up button events or other event handlers on pages and are removing them you may end up with some memory leaks if you don't manage them right.  This is why other more Object Oriented libraries or frameworks exist with JavaScript to support building apps, websites, or other activities, games etc. this way.  There are multiple approaches to this you'll find online which include transitions.  Some may load the new page, and unload the old.  Some may leave all the pages in the HTML Document adjusting their display and visibility parameters in CSS.  But it is a combined approach with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  Aside from jQTouch, Sencha Touch, and in some cases Backbone, etc...  Tutorials online can point you in a direction http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery--net-26.  Their are plenty of other options.  But this requires more management with backwards/forwards support if you need it, and an ability to maintain your navigation during suspend and resume.  I also have a example of this type of approach on my homepage https://cybercussion.com
3. you go the old school route of using a iframe to load your pages within it.  This route typically hurts mobile if thats on your horizon as it tends to weaken your frame rates, and put more stress on your viewports.